# how to check special time period in time frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have csv data from BTCUSDT prices and I want to know how can I check for example julys in these years of data. or how can I comparison first week of 12 months of a year.
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Binance_BTCUSDT1.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date

df['Date']
```

```
0       2021-06-06
1       2021-06-05
2       2021-06-04
3       2021-06-03
4       2021-06-02
           ...    
1386    2017-08-21
1387    2017-08-20
1388    2017-08-19
1389    2017-08-18
1390    2017-08-17
Name: Date, Length: 1391, dtype: object
```

Comment: Julys `dt.date.month == 7`?

Comment: if first week means first 7 days then `dt.date.day <= 7` ? If first week means first Monday to Sunday then it may need work - you may check every first day in month to get `dayname` and calculate when will be first `Monday`. And later you may try to get first weeks

Comment: I meant there are a lot of daily data in 5 years(5*365). For example I want to comparison spechially july's 31 days in these data. or comparison first 7 days of july.

Comment: if you use `dt.date.month == 7` then you will have all Julys. And if you use it with `dt.date.year` then you can select July in one year or you can use it with `groupby()` to group every July in separated group - and then you can compare groups. And if you use also `dt.date.day <= 7` then you can get first 7 days of July.

Answer (score 0):

All Julys

```
julys = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) ]
```

July 2016

```
july_2016 = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) & (df['Date'].dt.year == 2016)]
```

First 7 days in all Julys

```
julys_first_7_days = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) & (df['Date'].dt.day <= 7) ]
```

But more useful can be use `groupby` to create groups

```
julys_first_7_days = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) & (df['Date'].dt.day <= 7) ]

# split date
df['year']  = df['Date'].dt.year
#df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
#df['day']   = df['Date'].dt.day

julys_groups = julys_first_7_days.groupby('year')
```

And they you can work with every group separatelly

```
for index, grp in julys_groups:
    print('---', index, '---')
    print(grp)
```

or you can calculate some value for all groups - in. `mean price` for every group (every July)

```
means = julys_groups['price'].mean()
```

Result:

```
year
2016    5.571429
2017    5.571429
2018    6.285714
2019    6.142857
2020    4.285714
2021    4.857143
```

Or you can convert every year to column to compare day by day

```
julys_groups = julys_first_7_days.groupby('year')
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for index, grp in julys_groups:
    new_df[index] = grp['price'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
   2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
0     7     7     9     6     2     8
1     5     9     8     6     6     1
2     8     5     7     8     2     7
3     5     7     4     4     6     1
4     5     4     5     7     2     7
5     7     1     7     5     7     1
6     2     6     4     7     5     9
```

---

Minimal working code with random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2022-01-01', freq='d', closed='left'), columns=['Date'])
df['price'] = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(len(df),))

# split date
df['year']  = df['Date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['day']   = df['Date'].dt.day

# --- filter ---

julys = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) ]
print(julys)

july_2016 = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) & (df['Date'].dt.year == 2016)]
print(july_2016)

julys_first_7_days = df[ (df['Date'].dt.month == 7) & (df['Date'].dt.day <= 7)]
print(julys_first_7_days)

# --- groupby ---

# create groups using `julys_first_7_days`

julys_groups = julys_first_7_days.groupby('year')

for index, grp in julys_groups:
    print('---', index, '---')
    print(grp)

# means for every july in julys_first_7_days

means = julys_groups['price'].mean()
print('--- means ---')
print(means)

# convert groups to columns

julys_groups = julys_first_7_days.groupby('year')
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for index, grp in julys_groups:
    new_df[index] = grp['price'].reset_index(drop=True)
    
print(new_df)
```